# Replace a word in a text file, then output the overwritten version

Tags: c

For this problem I'm asked to first read from the input text file, prompt the user which word/string to get replaced, then output the **same** file (the original gets overwritten). The thing is the input/outputfile name must always have a specific name for example **test.txt** (this is what bothers me)

Here's the function which I tested out and it does the job replacing, but for now I'm prompting user to enter their own "sentence" and then for words. I'm lost on how to (always) read from a **test.txt** and then output the same one with replaced string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *w_replace(const char *s, const char *oldone, const char *newone)
{
char *ret;
int i, count = 0;
int newlen = strlen(newone);
int oldonelen = strlen(oldone);

for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (strstr(&s[i], oldone) == &s[i])
    {
        count++;
        i += oldonelen - 1;
    }
}
ret = (char *)malloc(i + count * (newlen - oldonelen));
if (ret == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
i = 0;
while (*s)
{
    if (strstr(s, oldone) == s) //compare 
    {
        strcpy(&ret[i], newone);
        i += newlen;
        s += oldonelen;
    }
    else
    ret[i++] = *s++;
}
ret[i] = '\0';
return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
char mystr[100], c[10], d[10];
char fileOld[32] = "test.txt";
char fileNew[32] = "test.txt";
char word_search[80];
char word_replace[80];
FILE *fp1, *fp2;

fp1 = fopen(fileOld,"r");
fp2 = fopen(fileNew,"w");

printf("Enter the word to replace :\n");
scanf(" %s",word_search);
printf("Enter the new word:\n");
scanf(" %s",word_replace);
char *newstr = NULL;

newstr = w_replace(fileOld, word_search , word_replace);


fputs(word_replace, fp2);
fclose(fp2);
fclose(fp1);
return 0;
}
```

So if a `test.txt` contains the following sentence

```
This is a test
```

Result

```
Enter the word to replace :
This
Enter the new word:
That
```

The new updated `test.txt` file will only be

```
That
```

instead of

```
That is a test
```

Comment: Recommend alternate approach.  Read from source file and write to a temporary file, changing the word/string as you go.  On successful completion change the name of the original file to a 2nd temporary name, Rename 1st temp file to original source file then delete the _original_ which now has a 2nd temporary name.  A bit laborious, but avoids ever losing the original file should some problem occur in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Needed values (using the var names you gave above):

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int file_descriptor;
int size_of_text = <whatever you want here>;
char *file_name = "test.txt";//or whatever
char newone[size_of_text];
char oldone[size_of_text];
```

To read from a file:

```
file_descriptor = open(file_name,O_RDONLY);//O_RDONLY opens for read only
read(file_descriptor,oldone,sizeof(oldone));//reads file into oldone
close(file_descriptor);//closes so you don't accidentally read or write to it later, and so you can use it again
```

To write to a file:

```
file_descriptor = open(file_name,O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);//O_WRONLY opens for writing only, O_TRUNC will truncate the file if it exists
write(file_descriptor,newone,sizeof(newone);//writes newone to file
close(file_descriptor);
```

For more information on read(),write(),open(),close():

http://www.gdsw.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm